# How to verify entire JSON response in JMeter 5.3?

Tags: json, jmeter, response

Is there a way to verify entire JSON response in JMeter 5.3? I saw some answers in different threads but need to verify the best solution in the latest version of JMeter?

I tried to use JSON assertion as below but it's gives an error.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON response is a regular response which you can use [Response Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion)

Set `Field to Test` as Text Response

> the response text from the server, i.e. the body, excluding any HTTP headers.

And in `Pattern Matching Rules` if you can validate JSON text as is use `Equals`

> Equals - true if the whole text equals the pattern string (case-sensitive)

If you need regular expression use Matches

> Matches - true if the whole text matches the regular expression pattern